# Query with count by groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have groups of categories  and group of ethnicity i need wright query for report  which will looks like this [image]

right now I have query  which can count by clients ID and ethnicity. However he is trick also client table has Hispanic field (bit 0 false 1 true). Client can have any ethnicity but in the same time he/she can be Hispanic.
my query right now can count client but for Hispanic it just  list count and not divide it  by ethnicity

```
select ethnicity, COUNT (c.EthnCode) as '(A) tottal Numbers of participamts by Rase', 
(select COUNT (Hispanic) from clients c JOIN ethnicity e
ON c.EthnCode = e.EthnCode
where c.EthnCode in ('N','A','B','P','W','NW','AW','BW','BN') and Hispanic =1 )as '(B)Number of Hispanic or Latino Participants Reported in Column A by Race'
from  Clients c
JOIN ethnicity e
ON c.EthnCode = e.EthnCode
where c.EthnCode in ('N','A','B','P','W','NW','AW','BW','BN')
group by ethnicity
```

Also If some ethnicity do not have perticipiants it just not showing it in result but i need to show 0 for that ethnicity.
here is the result of my query 
[image]

As you can see Hispanic not divided by category . 
Need Help trying to solve this problem second day  still no have any success

Comment: Not completely sure I understand your question -- what is your desired output?

Comment: in column 3 which right now shows 17 which is count of all clients in DB with Hispanic status 1 it should show them divided by ethnicity like in report example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select ethnicity, COUNT (c.EthnCode) as '(A) tottal Numbers of participamts by Rase', 
sum(case when Hispanic=1 then 1 else 0 end) as '(B)Number of Hispanic or Latino Participants Reported in Column A by Race'
from  Ethnicity E
LEFT JOIN Clients C
ON c.EthnCode = e.EthnCode
where e.EthnCode in ('N','A','B','P','W','NW','AW','BW','BN')
group by ethnicity
```

The SUM(CASE...) serves as a kind of "sub-count" within the actual count.

**UPDATE**:

In order to lump all the other codes into an "Other Multiples" category, do this:

```
select 
    case 
    when e.EthnCode in ('N','A','B','P','W','NW','AW','BW','BN') then ethnicity
    else 'Other Multiples' 
    end as ethnicity, 
    COUNT (c.EthnCode) as '(A) tottal Numbers of participamts by Rase', 
    sum(case when Hispanic=1 then 1 else 0 end) as '(B)Number of Hispanic or Latino Participants Reported in Column A by Race'
from  Ethnicity E
LEFT JOIN Clients C
ON c.EthnCode = e.EthnCode
group by case 
    when e.EthnCode in ('N','A','B','P','W','NW','AW','BW','BN') then ethnicity
    else 'Other Multiples' 
    end
```

This assumes that all the ethncodes in Ethnicity that aren't in your hardcoded statement are multiples.

Comment: thanx ! But how about those ethnicity which does not have any active clients like in my case it is AW which is Asian White. according to business rules this lines must be in report even if values in them is 0

Comment: I updated my answer for this. The short answer is you have to left join ethnicity to clients. So even if there are no clients, the ethnicity still gets returned, and its count and sum are both 0.

Comment: awesome!! May be you also helps me with the line 14 in original report which must also count all the clients by categories and ethnicity but only for those ethnicity which is not 'N','A','B','P','W','NW','AW','BW','BN' there is alot of combinations and they must be listed as one row with name some thing like multiple

Comment: Edited my answer again - I'll let you know my billing rate when we're done : )